# Existence of subgroup of Abel group

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G$ is a Abel group, the group of order is $n$. If there is an integer $m$ that is a factor of $n$, then there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ which order is $m$ .How to prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let G be our group of order $n$.
First you can use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic to say that $n$ is a unique product of distinct primes $p_i$: $$n = p^{k_1}_{1} \cdot p^{k_2}_{2} \cdot ... \cdot p^{k_{s}}_{s}.$$
Since $m$ is a divisor of $n$, we can write $m$ as a product of the same primes where the exponents of the primes may be $0$.
$$m =  p^{l_1}_{1} \cdot p^{l_2}_{2} \cdot ... \cdot p^{l_{s}}_{s}, \text{where } 0 \leq l_i \leq k_i. $$
The First Sylow Theorem gurantees the existence of groups of order equal to any power of a prime dividing $n$, we will choose the groups whose orders are $p^{l_i}_{i}$ and call them $H_{i} < G$. We know that these groups are all normal, because $G$ is abelian.
The last step will be the construction of the group $ H_1  H_2  ... H_s = H$ which we will show is isomorphic to $ H_1 \times  H_2 \times  ... \times H_s$ a group with order $m$.

Take any two $H_{i}, H_{j}$ where $i \neq j$ and suppose $a \in H_{i} \cap H_{j}$, then $o(a) \mid p_{i}$ and $o(a) \mid p_j$, which can only happen if $o(a) = 1$, since the primes $p_i, p_j$ are distinct. Then the intersection of any two such groups is trivial. (This step is needed to ensure unique representation of any element from $H$).

It's obvious elements from any two such groups commute since they lie in $G$ which is abelian, then we can show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with the required order.

Consider the map $\phi: H \rightarrow H_1 \times  H_2 \times  ... \times H_s, \phi(h_1h_2...h_s) = (h_1, h_2, h_3, ..., h_s)$.

**$\phi$ is a group homomorphism**: Obvious since $G$ is abelian.

**$\phi$ is injective**: ker$\phi = \{h_1h_2h_3...h_s \in H \mid h_1 = h_2 = ... = h_s = id \} = \{id\}$

**$\phi$ is surjective**: Obvious by construction.

Then we have shown $\phi$ is a group isomorphism between $H < G$ and $H_1 \times  H_2 \times  ... \times H_s$. Then $H$ is the subgroup of $G$ with order $m$.

Answer (score 0):

By the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, $G$ is a product of cyclic groups.

But cyclic groups have the property that there is a subgroup of order $d$ for any divisor of the order of the group.

The result now follows easily.

Incidentally, this is summed up by saying that finite abelian groups are "CLT groups".  That's they satisfy the converse to Lagrange's theorem.

The smallest group which isn't CLT is $A_4$ (no subgroup of order $6$).

Answer (score 0):

Assume $n=p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}\ldots p_r^{n_r}$,Since G is Abelian,Then we have an isomorphism f:
$$G\cong Z_{p_1^{n_1}}\oplus Z_{p_2^{n_2}}\oplus\ldots\oplus Z_{p_r^{n_r}}$$
assume $m=p_1^{l_1}p_2^{l_2}\ldots p_r^{l_r}$,
since: $Z_{p_i^{l_i}}\cong p_i^{n_i-l_i}Z_{p_i^{n_i}}<Z_{p_i^{n_i}}$,denote $$H=p_1^{n_1-l_1}Z_{p_1^{n_1}}\oplus p_2^{n_2-l_2}Z_{p_2^{n_2}}\oplus\ldots\oplus p_r^{n_r-l_r}Z_{p_r^{n_r}}$$then,we have:
$$H<Z_{p_1^{n_1}}\oplus Z_{p_2^{n_2}}\oplus\ldots\oplus Z_{p_r^{n_r}}$$
then,$f^{-1}(H)<G$,note that $|H|=m,|f^{-1}(H)|=m$.